# Reading and writing files python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to write three separate line in a text document based on input obtained from a dialogue window. I am sure this is a simple fix but I can't seem to write the three lines as separate lines. Would someone mind telling me what's wrong with this bit of code?

```
file = open('file.txt', 'wb') 
file.write('input1')
file.write('input2')
file.write('input3')
```

The inputs should be on different lines but instead they come out as:

```
input1input2input3
```

Instead of:

```
input1
input2
input3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
file = open('file.txt', 'wb')
file.write('input1\n')
file.write('input2\n')
file.write('input3\n')
```

You are appending the newline character `'\n'` to advance to the next line.

If you use the `with` construct, it will automatically close the file for you:

```
with open('file.txt', 'wb') as file:
   file.write('input1\n')
   file.write('input2\n')
   file.write('input3\n')
```

Also, consider using a different variable name in place of `file`.

Comment: The other one, which I don't like, but which is fairly common, being `print >>file, 'input1'`

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you haven't included newlines.  Remember, Python is outputting like a typewriter--you don't tell it to go to a new line, it won't.  The way to write a newline is `\n`.

So,

```
file.write('\n'.join([input1, input2, input3]))
```

Would do it.